# How can I create a Tkinter Entry widget that replaces user input with superscript after the user enters "^"?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to create a Tkinter Entry that allows a user to enter exponents into it. If the user types in "^", the Entry should ignore the "^" character, but enter the rest of the characters as superscript until the user presses space or an arrow key. So for example, if the user types "5x^2 +10", the text displayed should become "5x²+10".

I've tried making such a Tkinter entry by binding any keypress events to replace the regular text with superscript text right after a "^" is pressed. However, what I think is happening is the Entry is running the custom keypress code *before* it adds the character. So the Entry keeps the the user input instead of replacing it with the superscript.

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()


superscript_map = {
    "0": "⁰", "1": "¹", "2": "²", "3": "³", "4": "⁴", "5": "⁵", "6": "⁶",
    "7": "⁷", "8": "⁸", "9": "⁹", "a": "ᵃ", "b": "ᵇ", "c": "ᶜ", "d": "ᵈ",
    "e": "ᵉ", "f": "ᶠ", "g": "ᵍ", "h": "ʰ", "i": "ᶦ", "j": "ʲ", "k": "ᵏ",
    "l": "ˡ", "m": "ᵐ", "n": "ⁿ", "o": "ᵒ", "p": "ᵖ", "q": "۹", "r": "ʳ",
    "s": "ˢ", "t": "ᵗ", "u": "ᵘ", "v": "ᵛ", "w": "ʷ", "x": "ˣ", "y": "ʸ",
    "z": "ᶻ", "A": "ᴬ", "B": "ᴮ", "C": "ᶜ", "D": "ᴰ", "E": "ᴱ", "F": "ᶠ",
    "G": "ᴳ", "H": "ᴴ", "I": "ᴵ", "J": "ᴶ", "K": "ᴷ", "L": "ᴸ", "M": "ᴹ",
    "N": "ᴺ", "O": "ᴼ", "P": "ᴾ", "Q": "Q", "R": "ᴿ", "S": "ˢ", "T": "ᵀ",
    "U": "ᵁ", "V": "ⱽ", "W": "ᵂ", "X": "ˣ", "Y": "ʸ", "Z": "ᶻ", "+": "⁺",
    "-": "⁻", "=": "⁼", "(": "⁽", ")": "⁾"}


class ExponentEntry(Entry):
    def __init__(self, frame):
        super().__init__(frame)

        self.exponent_mode = False
        self.bind('<Key>', self.key_press)
        self.bind("<Down>", self.exit_exponent_mode)
        self.bind("<Right>", self.exit_exponent_mode())

    def key_press(self, event):
        current_text = self.get()
        if event.char == "^" and not self.exponent_mode:
            self.delete(0, END)
            self.insert(0, current_text[:-1])
            self.enter_exponent_mode()
        elif event.char == " " and self.exponent_mode:
            self.delete(0, END)
            self.insert(0, current_text[:-1])
            self.exit_exponent_mode()
        else:
            if self.exponent_mode:
                self.delete(0, END)
                self.insert(0, current_text[:-1] + superscript_map[event.char])

    def enter_exponent_mode(self):
        self.exponent_mode = True
        print("enter")

    def exit_exponent_mode(self):
        self.exponent_mode = False
        print("exit")


entry = ExponentEntry(root)
entry.pack()

mainloop()
```

Is there any way to fix the program?

Comment: Yes, the key binding is called *before* the character is actually inserted - that's what lets you modify or prevent the character from being inserted.  What you should do after handling a `^` keypress is `return "break"` - this prevents the Entry's normal key binding from inserting the character.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the default KeyPress event handler by returning `'break'` from your handler. Also, you can insert a character at the current cursor with `insert('insert', ...)`.

So, do like the following example.

```
class ExponentEntry(Entry):
    ...
    def key_press(self, event):
        current_text = self.get()
        if event.char == "^" and not self.exponent_mode:
            self.enter_exponent_mode()
            return 'break'
        elif event.char == " " and self.exponent_mode:
            self.exit_exponent_mode()
            return 'break'
        else:
            if self.exponent_mode:
                self.insert('insert', superscript_map[event.char])
                return 'break'
```